# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid when testing QueryRenderer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, jestjs

I am getting this error for each component that has QueryRenderer in it:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

"jest": "20.0.4"
"react-native": "0.47.1"
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
"react-relay": "^1.1.0"
```

Comment: Are you importing it?

Comment: yes sure, the code works fine, but test fails @RobbieMilejczak

Comment: this is a pretty straightforward error, the value of one of your components is undefined. Make sure that you're importing them correctly, and you're spelling all the names correctly. Particularly, don't forget to use proper capitalization. If you're absolutely sure that all of that is correct then if you're using custom components go to the files they are defined in and double triple check your export statements. I doubt this error has anything to do with Relay specifically